# How to traverse through 2d array and count how many elements are greater than 1 in each row in row major order

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, 2d

I'm writing a method that traverses  through a 2d array in row-major   order and at the start of each row, I   initialize a count variable to zero. In the inner loop, if a value is  non-zero I increment the count   variable. At the end of the row, if  the count variable is not exactly   equal to 1, return false. Ive been  working on this for about 2 weeks and   can't find my error. Please  point me in the right direction.
**  Don't mind the print statements I'm trying to see how much the count    is and my code only seems to hit the second row of the array

```
public static boolean isGPM(int[][] matrix) {
    int count =0;
    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
        count =0;
        for (int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {
            if (matrix[row][col] > 0) {
                count++;
            }
            else {
                return !gpm;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
    return gpm;
}
```

Comment: Issue with your inner loop else part. Check whether the count is not equal to one.

Comment: do you mean none zero or larger than zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you only care about the per-row count. This should work:

```
        int count = 0;

        // Process each row...
        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {

            count = 0;

            // Process each column...
            for (int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {

                 // Check the cell.
                 if (matrix[row][col] != 0) {
                     count++;
                 }                     
            }
            // Row processing complete. Check count.
            if (count != 1) {
                System.out.println(count);
                return gpm;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have to figure out the column count as well, but I figured that I would go through the rows first and do the same for columns but traverse through in column row order.

Comment: Is the matrix guaranteed to be a square 2D array? If so, the code in the answer above can be used for the row-major counts and a copy of the code can be modified, swapping the two for-lines to make it column-major. If the matrix is not a square 2D array, i.e. the rows aren't all the same length, you'll need to account for that in the column-major version of the code.

Comment: bless all of you